# How to change a ternary operator into an if-else statement?

Tags: javascript

How do I change this shorthand ternary operator into an if-else statement?

```
header.style.width = header.style.width === "1265px" ? '0px' : '1265px';
```

Comment: `if(condition) { assignmet } else { assignemet }`  ?

Comment: Here is a clue to help you plug the correct pieces of your code into what @CodeManiac said above: You want to assign the `header.style.width` property one value or another, conditional upon its current value. Think that through, edit your question with your best attempt, and we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

**[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**

**Syntax**

> condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

**Parameters**

> `condition`
>        An expression whose value is used as a condition.
>   `exprIfFalse`
>        An expression which is evaluated if the `condition` evaluates to a truthy value (one which equals or can be converted to `true`).
>   `exprIfFalse`
>        An expression which is executed if the `condition` is falsy (that is, has a value which can be converted to `false`).

To translate the above syntax into an [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement:

```
if(condition)
    exprIfTrue
else
    exprIfFalse
```

In your specific code:

```
header.style.width = header.style.width === "1265px" ? '0px' : '1265px';
```

You will have the following equivalent [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement:

```
if(header.style.width === "1265px")
    header.style.width = '0px';
else
    header.style.width = '1265px';
```

Comment:  You're welcome. Apologies in behalf of the unfriendly comments, but I agree with them that you should do your part first. Research, do your attempt in solving your problem first and then ask if you still cannot resolve it, showing your best attempt.